# separate html coded string and normal string

Tags: java, html, string

I want to split a single string containing normal text as well as html code into array of string. I tried to search on google but not found any suitable suggestion.

Consider the following string:

> blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah 
>   blahblah First para blahblahblahblah 
>   blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah
>
> ```
> <html>
>   <body>
>     <p>hello</p>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah 
>   blahblah Second Para lahblahblahblahblah 
>   blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah

this becomes:

```
s[0]=whole first para
s[1]=html code
s[2]=whole second para
```

Is it possible through `jsoup` ?. Or I need any other api?

Comment: could you not simply search for the <html> and </html> tags?

Comment: my string doesn't always contain html tags the string can also contain only body tags or any other html tags

Comment: is there a good reason to have a string structure like your example ?

Comment: @KarelG Simply it can be mail or an web page with html code etc

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with jQuery. Here below is a code snippet.

```
var str = "blablabla <html><body><p>hello</p></body></html> blabla";

var parsedHTML = $.parseHTML(str);
myList = [];

// loop through parsed text and put it into text based on its type
$.each(parsedHTML, function( i, el ) {
    if (el.nodeType < 3) myList[i] = el.nodeName;
    else myList[i] = el.data;
});
// use myList ...
```

Here is a fiddle which shows you that it works. The only disadvantage is that both `<html>` and `<body>` tag is parsed and not being obtained in the parsedHTML.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/32mxE/3/)

Comment: KarelG thanks for your answer but jquery doesn't works in java swing.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)

Simple use example:

```
String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
 + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

Then you can navigate the DOM structure to extract the information.

**update**

To get the text with all the tags you could wrap the entire string in `<meta>` ... `</meta>` tags; then parse it, access the individual components, and finally serialize the components back into strings.

Alternatively if you believe the code is well formed (with matching beginning and end tags) you could search for the first match of the regex

```
/<(html|body)\s*>/
```

Depending on what the contents of the first tag (match) are you then look for the last occurrence of the matching close tag.

More manual, more prone to error, not recommended. But since you have a non- standard problem it seems you might want a non-standard solution .

Comment: your code just removes all html tags from that string. But I want string with tags.